# 9 Volt battery connected with no resistance but current is not 9 A?

Tags: ohms-law

As per Ohms law , V = IR
OR
I = V/ R

So if I set R to 0 , then V should be equal to I ?

However when I connect 9 Volt battery poles to each other with multimeter in between the reading says 0.2 A.

Comment: your 9v battery is flat.

Comment: Mathematics 101.

Comment: @jasen what is flat ?

Comment: @Andyaka what is 101 ?

Comment: Flat -> Dead. 101 Basic Knowledge

Comment: Your math is wrong. I = 9/0 which is "infinity" or cannot be computed. However, resistance is never zero. And there is a concept you did not address, which is the internal resistance of a battery.

Comment: @MrCoder: "101" from a common numbering system for college/university level courses.  100 is the base level, usually first year.  101 is typically the first year introductory course for a given subject.  "Math 101" is therefore just a fancy way of saying "basic math."

Comment: @mkeith thanks for details , I undrestood my mistake now.

Comment: @JRE thanks for the explaination .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately for you, batteries have internal resistance. If they hadn't then you would have either blown your meter's current limit fuse or destroyed your meter.

Never short-circuit a battery or power supply with an ammeter. Always connect it in series with the load.

You can model your battery as an "ideal" 9 V battery with a series resistance. From you measurement you can calculate that the battery's internal resistance. \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {9}{0.2} = 45 \ \Omega \$.

---

From the comments:

> So does it mean if I short circuit 220 V (in house voltage), then reading should be 220 amps, since now there is no battery hence no internal resistance?

If there is no internal resistance on your 220 V supply then \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {220}{0} = \infty \ \text A \$.

Never short out a supply like that. Explosive amounts of energy can be released. (Look up "arc flash" on YouTube.) If you try it with your multimeter the results could be lethal.

Comment: so does it mean if I shortcircuit 220V (in house voltage) , then reading should be 220 Amps , since now there is no battery hence no internal resistance ?

Comment: Sigh 2.0........

Comment: @MrCoder See mkeith's comment above.  Your math is incorrect.

Comment: @HandyHowie thanks I made an error in calculations.

Comment: @MrCoder: See the update.

Answer (score 1):

First, as already said- don’t ever attempt to deliberately short any power source unless you are trying to obtain a UL rating for a device- you run a high risk of fire or (perhaps minor) explosion! I once worked for a power supply manufacturer and was assigned to do this sort of work one week- the supply was behind a blast shield for this reason.

Second, the ammeter itself has resistance in addition to the wires connecting it as well as the battery itself. There’s no way in a practical circuit to achieve zero resistance however close you might get and your current reading would only be 9A if the total resistance was exactly 1 ohm.

For internal resistance of typical battery types, see this article (the table therein shows a 9V zinc carbon battery is typically 35 ohms):

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Battery-internal-resistance